# How do I add an event inside of an XtraGrid GridColumn?

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

I have the following column defined inside of an XtraGrid.  The column consists of dropdowns that force a user to choose one of 3 options.  How can I wire an event that fires each time a user changes the value of a dropdown?

```
this.myCol.AppearanceCell.Options.UseTextOptions = true;
this.myCol.AppearanceCell.TextOptions.HAlignment = 
    DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Near;
this.myCol.Caption = "My Caption";
this.myCol.ColumnEdit = this._myRepositoryLookup;
this.myCol.FieldName = "MyFieldName";
this.myCol.Name = "myId";
this.myCol.Visible = true;
this.myCol.VisibleIndex = 5;
this.myCol.Width = 252;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to any  [RepositoryItemLookUpEdit Events](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEditClassEventsTopic), that you want to raise while working with these repository item controls.

For your requirement, you should use [RepositoryItem.EditValueChanged Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItem_EditValueChangedtopic), it Fires immediately after changing the edit value.

**Note**

> The EditValueChangedFiringMode property is ignored for lookup editors
>   during an incremental search while their popup windows are open. If
>   the editor's edit value is changed during an incremental search, the
>   EditValueChanged event fires immediately.

Code snippet:

```
_myRepositoryLookup.EditValueChanged += new EventHandler(_myRepositoryLookup_EditValueChanged);
this.myCol.AppearanceCell.Options.UseTextOptions = true;
this.myCol.AppearanceCell.TextOptions.HAlignment = 
                        DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Near;
this.myCol.Caption = "My Caption";
this.myCol.ColumnEdit = this._myRepositoryLookup;
```

LookupEdit event handler method

```
void _myRepositoryLookup_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
}
```

If you want to assign editors to individual cells then you can use [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic)

References that may help you:
[DevExpress RepositoryItemLookUpEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231621/devexpress-repositoryitemlookupedit)
[Get Cell Control of GridView in DevExpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020301/get-cell-control-of-gridview-in-devexpress)

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at

> GridView.CustomRowCellEdit Event or Repository Items Event

Here is a sample

using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;

```
private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) {
   if (e.Column.FieldName == "FieldName") return;
   GridView gv = sender as GridView;
   string fieldName = gv.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gv.Columns["FieldName"]).ToString();
   switch (fieldName) {
      case "Population":
         e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemSpinEdit1;
         break;
      case "Country":
         e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox1;
         break;
      case "Capital":
         e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemCheckEdit1;
         break;
   }           
}
```

Additional reading [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument747)

Answer (score 1):

Add an event directly to the Repository Item.

That way you can choose from the events of a Drop Down and not a column or cell.

```
repositoryItem.EditValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(repositoryItem_EditValueChanged);
```